# Isometric map tiles with Openlayers or similar

Tags: web-mapping

I wish to show a map layer in a browser based tool such as Openlayers or Leaflet however my tiles are projected isometrically.  Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map by mapbox does it the best way I've seen [Bike Share Map](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/dc-bikeshare-revisited/).

[image: MapBox Bike Share]

That tilts the whole map, though, and you might just want to render isometric tiles. I have no idea how they did it, I assume it's a combination of WebGl, magic and hard work.

The [Minecrafter](https://github.com/mapcrafter/mapcrafter) plugin for a Minecraft server does isometric tiles, but it's just a normal Leaflet map with fancy rendering. You could achieve the same thing by using building footprints and their height, for example.

[image: Minecrafter]

Final example is a little leaflet plugin that extrudes stuff, I have an example here with real data [Leaflet 3d Buildings](https://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/3dbuildings.html). Code is here: [maps.gcc 3d buildings](https://github.com/gccgisteam/maps-website/blob/master/3dbuildings.html).

[image: Glenorchy City Council's 3d Buildings example]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you intend something like http://maps.osm2world.org/

The wiki page should give you some guidance on how to render the tiles:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM2World/Maps

Answer (score 1):

Andre's solution works if you want to reproject the tiles, however I wished to retain my isometric projection.  Here's a way using leaflet:

Instead of creating a single layer, add an imageOverlay layer for each tile.  When the page is loaded or moved, check map bounds and add/remove layers as necessary.